# How to make pagination firebase in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a pagination limit to my request.
How to add pagination to a Firebase request in React? I need to add a limit when I get all lists.

```
const fetch_Contacts = async () => {
try {
 const sendReq = await getDocs(collection(db, "contacts")).then(
   (query_snapshot) => {
     const newData: any = query_snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
       ...doc.data(),
       id: doc. id,
     }));

     return newData;
   }
 );
 return sendReq;
} catch (error) {
 console.log("Get Contact Error =>", error);
}
};
```

Comment: It's right there in the docs ~ [Paginate data with query cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)